# How to avoid `require` and Access the controller of the parent component in transclusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to build a form component that receives an object as input and use the template defined into the object to ng-include the right template to render the form defined in the model.

The problem I have is the object might be defined in the above component. For example this:

```
   <somecomponent>
     <formx object="$ctrl.settings"></formx>
   </somecomponent>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. From what I read the transcluded block should be using the scope of the above controller. Is there a way to access the scope of the component `somecomponent`?

By the way, what I'm looking for is to do the same as:

```
 <div ng-controller="SomeController as ctrl">
   <formx object="ctrl.settings"></formx>
 </div>
```

But instead of using a plain controller I'd like to use a component without using an explicit require as the parent component might be different from time to time.

Comment: a transcluded block gets the controller of it's parent, not where it's transcluded to, so somecomponent has it's own controller, but formx has it's own controller, but can also access it's parent controller, and it's parent controller is NOT somecomponent, but the page / component they both reside within.

Comment: @bryan60 yes this is my problem as written in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With components the `ng-include` directive adds a child scope to the isolate scope. Transcluded components need to reference `$parent`:

```
<somecomponent settings="'ss'">
    ̶<̶f̶o̶r̶m̶x̶ ̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶=̶"̶$̶c̶t̶r̶l̶.̶s̶e̶t̶t̶i̶n̶g̶s̶"̶>̶<̶/̶f̶o̶r̶m̶x̶>̶
    <formx object="$parent.$ctrl.settings"></formx>
</somecomponent>
```

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xiNZqNTTKjj354tXJorx?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.component("somecomponent",{
  transclude: true,
  bindings: {settings:"<"},
  template: `
    <fieldset>
       somecomponent scope-{{$id}}
     <ng-transclude>
     </ng-transclude>
    </fieldset>
  `
})
.component("formx",{
  bindings: {object:"<"},
  template: `
     <fieldset>
       formx scope-{{$id}}<br>
       object={{$ctrl.object}}
     </fieldset>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
   <somecomponent settings="'ss'">
     <formx object="$parent.$ctrl.settings"></formx>
   </somecomponent>
  </body>
```

Comment: Ah right, I thought it should have been that simple but didn't see that `$parent` in the `$scope` while debugging. Thank you